# Count unique values in a filtered table without volatility

Tags: excel, unique, formula

I need to count the unique values in a column of a **filtered** table.

The formula must be in **one cell only** (no added columns with flags), and must be **non-volatile** (e.g. no OFFSET)

So far, I have this beast:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A3043) = SUBTOTAL(3, A1:A3043), SUMPRODUCT(1 * (A1:A3043 <> A2:A3044)),SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A3043)-ROW(A1),0,1)),MATCH(A1:A3043,A1:A3043,0)),ROW(A1:A3043)-ROW(A1)+1)>0,1)))
```

but it's very slow when filtering large tables due to it's volatility.

To be clear, if I filter "Item Purchased" in the following table, to just include the value *a*, then my unique count of customers would be 4 (customerIDs 1, 4, 5, 6):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get count of unique `Customer` for a corresponding `Item Purchased` use following formula

```
=SUM(IF("a"=$B$2:$B$12, 1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$12, "a", $A$2:$A$12, $A$2:$A$16)), 0))
```

or

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$12="a",MATCH($A$2:$A$12,$A$2:$A$12,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

where, `A2:B12` is the data range and replace `a` with any item purchased. This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

To get count of unique customer for all item purchased, enter the following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$16),0,0),0)),"")
```

drag/copy down as required.

Then in `Cell E2` enter below array formula

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$16=D2,MATCH($A$2:$A$16,$A$2:$A$16,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

or

```
=SUM(IF(D2=$B$2:$B$16, 1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$16, D2, $A$2:$A$16, $A$2:$A$16)), 0))
```

drag/copy down as required. Being an array formula, commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To count the unique values in **filtered** column, please use this formula

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A35)-ROW(A2),,1)),IF(A2:A35<>"",MATCH("~"&A2:A35,A2:A35&"",0))),ROW(A2:A35)-ROW(A2)+1),1))
```

If your data is in columns `A:B` enter this formula in cell `D1`. When entering you should press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER since this is array formula.

[image]

I don't think you can achieve this without volatile Offset formula, but this formula might be a bit faster.

Comment: I don't think this quite works. On the OP's unfiltered list it returns 6 when it should be returning 12. This is due to the formula only considering the customer as unique instead of the customer + item

Comment: Your statement is true, but again, he didn't mention anything about customer+item that needs to be unique. He said that he needs to count only unique customers.

Comment: Fair enough. I was reading'unique values' as the whole row but have now seen in the last paragraph OP does say unique customers.

Comment: Could the OFFSET be replaced with an INDEX?

Comment: Hm, not sure since it is used to create an array. Did you consider maybe setting your calculations to manual when entering data/working with worksheet ranges. That way your performance will not be impacted by volatile formulas? then after you finished all work, set calculations back to automatic...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$12<>"")*SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($A$2,ROW($A$2:$A$12)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$12)),0)))/COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,B2:B12))
```

This will count all unique values in a filtered list. The issue that you've got is you need `OFFSET` for the visibility of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom's answer was close enough, but when only showing one item, it didn't answer properly...it had some decimals if I did NOT show the last item in the filter, so here is a fixed version:

> =SUMPRODUCT(((Table13[Person]<>"")*SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table13[[#Headers],[Person]],ROW(Table13[Person])-MIN(ROW(Table13[Person]))+1,0)))/COUNTIFS(Table13[Person],Table13[Person]))

Notice the plus 1 to fix the decimals.
I also don't know why he was looking at column B either.